# R: Convert list of lists with varying number of items to dataframe

Tags: json, r, list

List-to-dataframe have been extensively discussed [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/converting-a-list-to-a-data-frame/) but I couldn't find a solution for quite a simple problem: a list of lists with varying number of items.

This is the list

```
require(json)
hdi <- fromJSON(file="http://data.undp.org/resource/y8j2-3vi9.json")
```

with the first list of the list being

```
hdi[1]
[[1]]
[[1]]$`_2011_hdi_value`
[1] "0.887"

[[1]]$`_1990_hdi_value`
[1] "0.798"

[[1]]$`_2000_2013_average_annual_hdi_growth`
[1] "0.37"

[[1]]$`_1980_hdi_value`
[1] "0.757"

[[1]]$`_2010_hdi_value`
[1] "0.885"

[[1]]$`_2008_hdi_value`
[1] "0.879"

[[1]]$`_1990_2000_average_annual_hdi_growth`
[1] "0.62"

[[1]]$`_2012_hdi_value`
[1] "0.889"

[[1]]$`_2013_hdi_value`
[1] "0.890"

[[1]]$`_2005_hdi_value`
[1] "0.870"

[[1]]$`_2000_hdi_value`
[1] "0.849"

[[1]]$country
[1] "Very high human development"

[[1]]$`_1980_1990_average_annual_hdi_growth`
[1] "0.52"
```

yet the number of items  across lists varies

```
summary(as.numeric(summary(hdi)[,"Length"]))
#   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#   5.00   16.00   16.00   14.93   16.00   16.00
```

I want to build a dataframe with 16 columns with `NA` indicating the missing value for that list.

Comment: Where would these NAs be in the resulting data frame and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest is

```
data <- jsonlite::fromJSON("http://data.undp.org/resource/y8j2-3vi9.json")
```

Or, using `rlist`

```
library(rlist)
data <- list.stack(hdi, fill=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
 require(RJSONIO)
 hdi <- fromJSON("http://data.undp.org/resource/y8j2-3vi9.json")
 #get the unique values of the column names
 columnnames<-unique(unlist(lapply(hdi,names)))
 #subset each element of the list with and rbind them together
 res<-do.call(rbind,lapply(hdi,function(x) x[columnnames]))
 colnames(res)<-columnnames
```

From there, you can coerce the numeric column and coerce the object to a `data.frame`. I suggest you to use the `RJSONIO` library to handle conversion from/to json as it seems to be more reliable in my experience.